# Is it possible to easily have different config files for development locally and production on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I currently deployed my app on Heroku but suddenly discovered (which is madness in my opinion) that once slug is made, you can't change it without a new push from your repo.

The problem is I designed my code to have different config files for development and production, and now it doesn't seem possible to insert my production configs to the Heroku deployment independently from git push!

I understand that technically config files functionality can be replaced by environmental variables and database feed. But honestly I would rather just ditch Heroku than redesign my code.

So, do I miss something? Or is there an easy way to have different config files locally and on my Heroku deployment? I intend to update my code a lot, so it is not an option to each time swap config files, adding and committing all these changes, and making a mess out of my git logs. Not to mention it would be a bad practice in general and asking for constant hiccups and troubles. All because I MUST for some reason upload my configs only through git push, having no other way. So is there a better option, or should I go straight to Software Recommendations and ask for good alternatives for Heroku?

Comment: If you don't want to replace all access to your config with access to env vars, have _one_ env var that has the path to config file. It has minimal impact on your code (just the place you load your config file), and will let you keep separate config files for Heroku and dev. However, one of the benefits of using env vars is lost (never commit secrets to a repo).

Comment: Thanks, Amadan! I am using Node and Express. I wonder if it is possible to require config files from a different host? Besides that what would be the way to do it securely? Configs have a good amount of sensitive data, so it can't be publicly available.

Comment: Environment variables are the way to pass sensitive data securely. While you _could_ get your data from a remote host... so could an attacker, presumably.

Comment: Thanks again! Guess I would just do a server with Node myself...